# Differences in Java Security Providers

Tags: java

I am using **JRE 1.7** with Unlimited java policy

Checking java.security.Security.getProviders() on Mac returns following -

```
Provider[0]:: SUN 1.7
Provider[1]:: SunRsaSign 1.7
Provider[2]:: SunEC 1.7
Provider[3]:: SunJSSE 1.7
Provider[4]:: SunJCE 1.7
Provider[5]:: SunJGSS 1.7
Provider[6]:: SunSASL 1.7
Provider[7]:: XMLDSig 1.0
Provider[8]:: SunPCSC 1.7
Provider[9]:: Apple 1.1
```

But checking on Linux does not return Apple 1.1 one

```
Provider[0]:: SUN 1.7
Provider[1]:: SunRsaSign 1.7
Provider[2]:: SunEC 1.7
Provider[3]:: SunJSSE 1.7
Provider[4]:: SunJCE 1.7
Provider[5]:: SunJGSS 1.7
Provider[6]:: SunSASL 1.7
Provider[7]:: XMLDSig 1.0
Provider[8]:: SunPCSC 1.7
```

This is causing issues in our Linux boxes, how can we make sure it also returns Apple ?

Comment: Shouldn't you better make sure you don't rely on OS-specific providers?

Comment: Not actually, my main concern is how come Apple is getting added even though i am using same US_export_policy.jar and local_policy.jar

Comment: Because it's a different JVM?

Comment: Thats what I wanted to know ..does it depend on platform ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default list of security providers is coming with the JVM. It can be both JVM vendor specific and platform specific.

The static list of default security providers is defined in `$JAVA_HOME/lib/security/java.security`.

The policy files, that you are referring to, are defining security algorithm usage policies.